# Sound on changed keyboard layout

Tags: windows, keyboard

Many years irritates me windows keyboard layout changing on Alt+SHIFT. It is slow, i never know what keyboard is currently switched.
I need application what checks keyboard layout and plays different sound on change keyboard. Exist something like this?

Comment: Never noticed that command (Left Alt + Shift)(I'm on Windows XP by the way)... Maybe there is something in System Sounds. You can always see the keyboard layout in the taskbar or by activating the idioms bar.

Comment: I didn't find any event linked to that but [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ff08dda2-18fd-4502-8472-b88c5b4dad90/annyoing-sound-when-switching-keyboard-language-in-windows-7?forum=w7itproui) divulges a anti-problem and [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-computer-sounds) describes how to access the Sound Scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer I can give you is the one [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/sound-notification-of-the-change-between-keyboard/ff876784-7847-47ea-baaa-65b9599578e3) gives:

> Unfortunately, there isn’t any setting where you can set a sound notification for the change in keyboard layout unless otherwise there is a software that can help you do so.
>
> In Windows 7, there are certain default sounds which play for the default actions. You can set sounds for some of them but not for the one you are looking for, that is when the keyboard layout changes.

That post does indicate the existence of software that can do what you want, a search revealed [R-WIN 32](http://www.proximasoftware.com/rwin).

> R-WIN 32 is a set of Multilingual support utilities for users working with two or more input languages at the same time - English, German, Russian, and other languages.
>
> Includes utilities and fonts:
>
> Keyboard Switch
>
> - Switches current language, supports convenient hot keys, small floating window with flag image, custom images and **sounds assigned to language**.

Answer (score 1):

[AutoHokey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) can play a sound when a hotkey is pressed. I found [a script on the forum](http:////autohotkey.com/board/topic/109800-ctrl-shift-issue/?p=651946)

```
~+Ctrl Up::
~^Shift Up::

if (A_ThisHotkey = "~+Ctrl Up")
  KeyWait, Shift
else
  KeyWait, Ctrl

if instr(A_PriorKey, "Control") || instr(A_PriorKey, "Shift")
  SoundPlay, ./files/lang_change.wav

return
```

The script plays sound located in the `files` subfolder near script file when Ctrl+Shift is pressed and released.

Detecting the current keyboard layout [is not simple](http://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=63062)